# Python - Referencing class name from inside class body

Tags: python, static, class-attributes

In Python, I want to have a class attribute, a dictionary, with initialized values. I wrote this code:

```
class MetaDataElement:
    (MD_INVALID, MD_CATEGORY, MD_TAG) = range(3)
    mapInitiator2Type = {'!':MetaDataElement.MD_CATEGORY, 
                         '#':MetaDataElement.MD_TAG}
```

But when I try to run this code, I get an error message with "NameError: name 'MetaDataElement' is not defined". Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot refer to `MetaDataElement` while it is being constructed, since it does not yet exist.  Thus,

```
class MetaDataElement:
    (MD_INVALID, MD_CATEGORY, MD_TAG) = range(3)
    mapInitiator2Type = {'!':MetaDataElement.MD_CATEGORY, 
                         '#':MetaDataElement.MD_TAG}
```

fails because the very construction of `mapInitiator2Type` requires `MetaDataElement` to have attributes, which it does not yet have.  You can think of your constants `MD_INVALID`, etc. as variables that are local to the construction of your class.  This is why the following works, as icktoofay wrote:

```
class MetaDataElement:
    (MD_INVALID, MD_CATEGORY, MD_TAG) = range(3)
    mapInitiator2Type = {'!': MD_CATEGORY,  # MD_CATEGORY is like a local variable!
                         '#': MD_TAG}
```

However, you can refer to the class `MetaDataElement` in any yet un-interpreted piece of code, as in

```
    def method_of_MetaDataElement(self):
        print MetaDataElement.MD_TAG
```

You even *have* to refer to `MetaDataElement`, here, because `MD_TAG` is not a kind of local variable when `method_of_MetaDataElement()` is executed (`MD_TAG` was only defined as a kind of local variable during class construction).  Once the class `MetaDataElement` is created, `MD_TAG` is simply a class attribute, which is why `method_of_MetaDataElement()` must refer to it as such.

Comment: The final example could be written with `self.MD_TAG`, which avoids any need to refer to the class name.

Comment: @Marcin: `self.MD_TAG` is also a possibility, but it is not equivalent to `MetaDataElement.MD_TAG`, if `MetaDataElement` is subclassed (subclasses might overwrite `MD_TAG`). Both are valid, but which one to choose depends on the situation at hand.

Comment: Honestly, I think it's probably wrong for methods to prevent subclasses from being able to usefully alter class members, which is why I would recommend using `self` unless there is a specific reason to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using old-style classes. You should probably use new-style classes, like so:

```
class MetaDataElement(object):
    ...
```

Note the `(object)`. Anyway, though, simply remove the `MetaDataElement.` when referring to the class attributes. This is what it'd look like when that's done:

```
class MetaDataElement(object):
    (MD_INVALID, MD_CATEGORY, MD_TAG) = range(3)
    mapInitiator2Type = {'!': MD_CATEGORY, 
                         '#': MD_TAG}
```

Comment: Maybe redism is writing in Python 3 and *is* using new-style classes. :)

Comment: @EOL: I wasn't aware that Python 3 used new-style classes by default. That's good to know.

Comment: Here is the reference: "Classic classes are gone." (http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax)